# Fullscreen API suddenly stopped working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

this is super weird - I was working on my React App with requestFullscreen() triggered by a user gesture and it was working. After refactoring the code for a little bit (without changing much functionality, the same function has stopped working (it wouldn't go into fullscreen). So I was just testing it in the console, with things like:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.requestFullscreen()
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

  console.log(e)
})
```

And it will sometimes it will do nothing (logs the events) and sometimes it throws a fullscreen error, telling me that it can only be triggered by a user gesture (despite it is clearly triggered by a click). What confused me the most is the fact that it once worked, and now it wouldn't even do anything if I add an event listener in the console. I don't think it is a compatibility problem as I have tested other fullscreen methods (i.e. webkit)

Comment: I semi-solved it but I still don't know why it worked: there's a window resize listener down the event chain, so I stopped propagation after the resize event is triggered. I don't know why this worked or what event was originally propogated after that. I do have a setstate in the resize listener callback if that's related.

Comment: This is so mind boggling! I removed the e.stopPropagation() line and it still worked (let me fullscreen)! I don't know what changed because my code is the same as when I started. Is this a chrome thing?

Comment: ...and now it doesn't. I am truly lost.